# Exception in class

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.<init>(HttpMethodBase.java:220)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.ExpectContinueMethod.<init>(ExpectContinueMethod.java:93)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.<init>(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:119)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod.<init>(PostMethod.java:106)
    at SMSServiceJava.CSoftHttpClientSMSService.sendSimpleSMS(CSoftHttpClientSMSService.java:113)
    at SMSServiceJava.CSoftHttpClientSMSService.main(CSoftHttpClientSMSService.java:219)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

whenever I am running the program in eclipse I am getting the above mentioned exception. whenever I already been passed the relevant package in my classpath. can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using any external library?

Comment: What jars do you have on your classpath ?

Comment: Try adding commons-codec-1.2.jar if it does not already exist on your classpath

Comment: Thanks dude. after adding commons.codec.jar 1.2 version the issue got resolved. prev i was using commons.codec.jar 1.8 version & in that jar file i was getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the jar(Commons-codec.jar) file needed for this org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException

Download it from here and put it in classpath

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi

Answer (score 1):

You need [commons-codec.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi) on your classpath.

Reference: [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685527/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-co)

Comment: Thanks now it is working. after adding org.apache.commons.codec.jar version 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `org-apache-commons-codec.jar` is present on your class-path. You can download this [commons-codec jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi) file from apache website. 
This jar file contains `org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException` class, and hence add it to the classpath must resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time. For example if we have a method call from a class or accessing any static member of a Class and that class is not available during run-time then JVM will throw `NoClassDefFoundError`.

For [`more`](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to include commons-codec-XXX.jar.