# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory in solrj and jsf context

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm getting above exception for this line:

```
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient("<host>");
```

Adding commons-logging-1.2.jar as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551697/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-logging-logfactory) didn't change anything; nor did adding commons-codec-1.10.jar suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685527/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-co).

My app is a JSF web application deployed in Glassfish 4.0 .

Comment: where did you add those? Are they deployed on the server, did you check?

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the problem. I only added them locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only adding the jars locally in the NetBeans IDE. Once I added them as dependencies in the maven file instead, all is good.